# Title: "Flutter Firebase Auth with Azure AD - 'firebase_auth/invalid-credential' Error (HTTP 401)"

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am facing an issue with authentication while trying to sign in from Microsoft using Firebase and Azure AD in my flutter app. The error message I am encountering is as follows:

```
  Error: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] 

   HttpMetadata{status=401, 

   cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, 
     cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, 
    staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, 

     lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null,    

     crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null,

     crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     I/flutter (10985):
     I/flutter (10985): , contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], reportToHeaders=[], 
   varyHeaderNames=[], cookieList=[]}}
```

I have integrated Firebase with Azure AD for authentication, and the setup seems to be correct. However, I'm unable to identify the root cause of this issue.

I have double-checked the credentials, reviewed the integration settings, and ensured that the Azure AD application has the necessary permissions. Despite these efforts, the HTTP 401 status indicates unauthorized access.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can provide some insight into what might be causing this issue? Any suggestions or tips on troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have tried this code for microsoft login

```
 final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
            final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
           
            //microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters(customOAuthParameters);

            try {
              // Perform the Microsoft authentication using signInWithPopup or signInWithProvider
              // (Code omitted here based on the previous implementation)
              if (kIsWeb) {
                await auth.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
              } else {
                final UserCredential result =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
        print(result);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text(result.toString())));

                
              }

              // Once successfully authenticated, retrieve the access token
              
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the authentication process.
              print('Error: $e');
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Message:$e')));
            }
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find any solution to this?